# php provoke a php file from popen() with arguments or parenthesis

Tags: php

I have been trying to do this:

```
$handle = popen('php -q nah.php?part='. $part . ' 2>&1', 'r');
while (!feof($handle))
{
    $read = fread($handle, 2096);
    echo $read;
}
pclose($handle);
```

What i want to do is i want to pass some values to the file nah.php but When i try it this way i get an error this :

> Could not open input file: nah.php?part=say:

How can i do this ?

And yea i am using all this php-cli

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Used in command-line, PHP doesn't take GET arguments but command-line arguments, for example:

```
php -q nah.php -p='name of part'
```

You can then get the value of these arguments using [getopt()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php):

```
$options = getopt("p:");
$part = $options["p"];
```

Comment: your link to `getopt()` was pointing to the French translation. I've edited it to the English version. But +1 for the good answer.

Comment: And how would the nah.php look in the 2nd case ?

Comment: @Spudley: Thanks! As a French-speaker, I just didn't think about it.

Comment: @kritya: What do you mean, 2nd case?

Comment: With the getopt() how will i get what is passed will it be also in $arg ?

Comment: With the code I wrote, **$part** contains what is passed through the **-p** option.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to run PHP from the command line, but passing URL type arguments to it.

URL arguments do not work in the command line context; they're being treated as part of the file name.

Arguments need to be passed in as per any other CLI program, as space separated strings.

Inside your PHP program, you also won't get anything in `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`. To process CLI arguments, you need to read them from STDIN.

See here for more info on how to do that: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php#81470